# Parameter returning undefine and php select by id returning null

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, parameters

someone should pls help me out on this.

I need to select and update data by id from SQL database but i am not getting the appropriate result.
The php file is returning null. When i checked from my developer tool, i realised that the params code, `this.props.match?.params.id` is showing undefined. I guess it is not able to send the id parameter to the "$id" in the edit.php code.

Someone should please help me look into the codes. I want to be able to select and edit based on specific id from the database.
Thank you
Here is my code;

edit.php

```
<?php

require 'connect.php';
include_once("Core.php");
    
$id = $_GET['id'];


//Get by id

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `visitors` WHERE `id` ='{$id}' ";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

// print_r($row)

echo $json = json_encode($row);
exit;
```

The update code is bellow

update.php

```
<?php
include_once("Core.php");
require 'connect.php';

//Get the posted data
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");

if(isset($postdata) && !empty($postdata))
{
    // Extract the data
   $request = json_decode($postdata);

        print_r($request);
    
        // Sanitize
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $lastName= $request -> lastName;
        
        // Update
        $sql = "UPDATE `visitors` SET `lastName` = '$lastName'  WHERE `id` = '{$id}' LIMIT 1";
    
            if(mysqli_query($con, $sql))
            {
                http_response_code(201);
            }
            else
            {
                http_response_code(422);
            }
    }
```

For the edit code

edit.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Edit.css";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import Axios from "axios";

export default class Edit extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onChangeLastName = this.onChangeLastName.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get(
            "http://localhost/testing/edit.php?id=" + this.props.match?.params.id
        )
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({
                    firstName: response.data.firstName,
                    lastName: response.data.lastName,
                });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
    // }

    onChangeLastName(e) {
        this.setState({
            lastName: e.target.value,
        });
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const obj = {
            lastName: this.state.lastName,
        };

        Axios.post(
            "http://localhost/testing/update.php?id=" + this.props.match?.params.id,
            obj
        ).then((res) => console.log(res.data));

        this.setState({
            lastName: "",
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="edit">
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <div className="edit__text">Date & Time Out:</div>

                    <label>
                        Last Name:
                        <input
                            name="last"
                            type="text"
                            value={this.state.lastName}
                            onChange={this.onChangeLastName}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <button>Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.props.match.id
```

This code is no longer valid in react,
It has been replaced by useParams hook

```
...
  const id = useParams();

   componentDidMount() {
    Axios.get(
        "http://localhost/testing/edit.php?id=" + id;
    )
 ...
```

This should work, and you need to import the hook too.